# Как реализовать OrbitControls и загрузку своей модели в Three.js? Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js

Пытаюсь разобраться в three.js по документации, но не понимаю как реализовать возможность вращать модель мышкой? Т.е. Я понимаю, что для этого служит OrbitControls, но когда вместо анимации пытаюсь использовать его, копируя код прямиком из документации, то модель вообще не появляется. Вместо неё появляются ошибки:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module(STLLoader.js:58)
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module(OrbitControls.js:10)
(index):48 Uncaught ReferenceError: OrbitControls is not defined at (index):45(помечу строчку в коде)
```

Да, та же проблема с `STLLoader.js` (хоть он пока и не нужен, но конечная цель - загрузить свою модель), я пытался делать и через импорты, и прописывать `type="module"` для скриптов, но проблема +- та же, либо сцены нет вообще, либо модель не появляется. Для меня это странно, т.к. three.js подключена тем же путём но она работает.

Код:

```
<body>
<script src="js/three.js"></script>
<script src="js/STLLoader.js"></script>
<script src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script>
    //Сцена
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    //Камера
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    //Рендерер, размером с область камеры, пустой canvas
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    //Фигура с геометрией и материалом
    const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(10, 3, 16, 100);
    const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    //Сетка принимающая геометрию и применяющая материал + позиция камеры
    const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(sphere);
    //Новая сцена для света, + цвет света, позиция.
    const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xeeeece);
    spotLight.position.set(1000, 1000, 1000);
    scene.add(spotLight);
    //Ещё один свет
    const spotLight2 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
    spotLight2.position.set(-200, -200, -200);
    scene.add(spotLight2);

    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement); // - строка с ошибкой.
    camera.position.set( 0, 20, 100 );
    controls.update();
    //Анимация, рендеринг
    function render() {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        controls.update();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    render();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если использовать ES6-модули, как во всех официальных примерах, то их нужно импортировать с помощью `import`. Тогда основной файл Three.js будет `three.module.js`, остальное берется из папки `examples\jsm`:

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import * as THREE from "https://threejs.org/build/three.module.js";
import {OrbitControls} from "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

    //Сцена
    const scene = new THREE.Scene();
    //Камера
    const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
    //Рендерер, размером с область камеры, пустой canvas
    const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    //Фигура с геометрией и материалом
    const geometry = new THREE.TorusGeometry(10, 3, 16, 100);
    const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
    //Сетка принимающая геометрию и применяющая материал + позиция камеры
    const sphere = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(sphere);
    //Новая сцена для света, + цвет света, позиция.
    const spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xeeeece);
    spotLight.position.set(1000, 1000, 1000);
    scene.add(spotLight);
    //Ещё один свет
    const spotLight2 = new THREE.SpotLight(0xffffff);
    spotLight2.position.set(-200, -200, -200);
    scene.add(spotLight2);

    const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement); // - строка с ошибкой.
    camera.position.set( 0, 20, 100 );
    controls.update();
    //Анимация, рендеринг
    function render() {
        requestAnimationFrame(render);
        controls.update();
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
    render();
</script>
```

`OrbitControls` используется для перемещения камеры вокруг объекта, объект при этом остается на месте.

PS Сообщают, что в ревизии 124 не будет больше скриптов в папке `examples\js` (и папки самой тоже не будет, наверное :) ) Поэтому лучше сразу ориентироваться на ES6-модули из `examples\jsm`, то есть смотреть, как оно сделано в официальных примерах.

Comment: А не подскажите, как с помощью form можно реализовать загрузку любой модели с ПК, как тут http://jinjunho.github.io/Madeleine.js/ или тут https://3dnetprint.ru/3d-preview/ ?

Comment: Можно сделать так же, как это сделано в [редакторе сцен](https://threejs.org/editor/), куда можно загружать файлы с моделями во всех поддерживаемых в Three.js форматах: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/0e7e3af78809039e65c6300370415354ca8dae69/editor/js/Loader.js#L95